# Probably simple bitwise shifting question

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

```c
unsigned short int temp, temp2;

temp = 0xbc61; // 1011110001100001
// temp2 has to be 0x61 (01100001) but I don't know how to shift, mask or whatever
temp2 = (temp << 8); // this doesnt work, because I get 0x6100 (110000100000000)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47981/6872717

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To select the 8 lowest bits of `1011110001100001`, you need to perform a bitwise AND operation with `11111111`:

```
  1011110001100001
& 0000000011111111
------------------
  0000000001100001
```

That is,

```
temp2 = temp & 0xff;  // or 255
```