# Changing only some bits with mask

Tags: c, bit-manipulation

I need help with finding the correct bit mask.
0xbc61 has to be 0xbcaa, but I am not sure how to create the bit mask to affect only the part I have to change.
I also tried splitting the value but wasn't sure how to "glue" them with the new one...

```c
unsigned short int left, right;
unsigned short int temp = 0xbc61;
unsigned short int newValue = 0xaa;
right= temp & 0xff; // split
left= (temp >> 8) // split

// temp needs to be 0xbcaa
// and I also need it the other way round, so 0xbc61 -> 0xaa61
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/56610742/905902

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean `newValue = (oldValue & 0xff00) | 0xaa;`? Or you need to use minimal mask? If so, write your number in binary and check it. :)

Comment: That's it! Thank you very much. Will accept your answer in 5 minutes when I am allowed to.

Comment: `(oldValue & 0xff) | 0xaa00` ? :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `XOR` here:

`0x61` is `0b01100001`

`0xaa` is `0b10101010`

To convert one value into another just use `XOR` with `0xCB` (`0b11001011`):

```
unsigned short mask = 0xbc61;
....
// convert to new mask 0xbcaa
mask ^= 0xCB; // mask now is 0xbcaa
...
// convert back to 0xbc61
mask ^= 0xCB; // mask now is 0xbc61
```

**NOTE**: `A XOR 1 = !A` and `A XOR 0 = A`

Here is the demo: https://ideone.com/UIxPDV

Answer (score 1):

to change any arbitraty bits to anothers:

```
uint32_t changebits(uint32_t val, uint32_t mask, uint32_t newvalue)
{
    val &= ~mask;
    val |= (newvalue & mask);
    return val
}
```

---

```
 changebits(0xe323da98, 0b00000110011000010100000100000000, 0xde45ab67);
```

it will set only the bits given by the second parameters to the same bits from the third parameter.

in your case

```
changebits(0xbc61, 0xff, 0xaa);
```